# Update database without refresh when making change to form field

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, database, refresh

So, I have a row in a table called player. I want to be able to update the field: "Name".

At the front end I have already displayed a form text input field with the value already automatically set to the current value of Name from the table. I have given this an id="currentName".

Using Javascript, AJAX and JQuery (or anything similar) I want to be able to have the value for Name automatically updated in the database when a user makes a change to the contents of this field.

I have looked at other resources but as I'm new to many of these languages I'm struggling to do it in my context.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using jquery ajax you can bind on change event to that field and then use ajax to  update that table with the value. Now there are two ways validating the input you can use .blur when the user loses focus to check if the value has changed or you can handle a back-end check.

```
$("#currentName").change(function(){
        $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "~/yoururl/functions.php",//your url here
                    data: $(this).val(),  //this is the current value that was changed
                    dataType: 'json',
                    success: function(response) {
                        console.log("success");
                    },
                    error: function(response) {
                        console.log(response);
                    }
                });
    });
```

//process flow for clarity

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the reply! So what is the purpose of the url in the example you gave me? Trying to get my head round it. Thanks.

Comment: Okay so the url is where you post your data to (Back-end) if you are using a c# or web api of some sort you will post it to a web method that handles the business logic and data insertion of your value. In this case it will post data to a php file which will have a check to see what data is post something like $_POST['data'] then you can use this to do a mysqli or T-SQL update to the database. PHP is a server side scripting language just for clarity.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, so in my PHP file i can make the change to the database as required, and I assume if I dont return a .html file the update will have worked without the page refreshing?

Comment: You don't return an html file, all that you need to check if the response from the server was successful is to log it to the console. in the response section:  success: function(response) {
                        console.log(response);
                    },  // If this returns Status 200 (OK) then it was successful and the data has inserted. :) Magic, you will use something like "mysqli_error($con));" in php to return errors on the response.

Comment: Sounds great. Thanks very much for the help. What would i put in the PHP file to get the updated field? $_POST["#nameoffieldhere"]?

Comment: Query that row, it will be a good indication that the value also correctly updated and then echo **if (isset($_POST['currentName']) && isset($_POST['userID'])) {
   $userID = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['userID']);
   $currentName = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['currentName']);
   $resultcurrentName = $conn->query("SELECT currentName FROM tableNames WHERE userID='" . $userID . "'");
   
   if ($resultcurrentName->num_rows > 0) {
    $resultcurrentName = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultcurrentName);
    
    echo json_encode(resultcurrentName['columNameCurrentUser']);
   }
 }

Comment: Hope this helped for you bud.